# Is there an ethereum android wallet where I don't have to manually add in tokens I have and just auto detects it?

Tags: tokens, wallets, android, mobile-wallet

Using coinomi or even metamask on chrome is quite annoying as I need to manually add in tokens I have in my account and it doesn't auto show up. Is there an android or desktop ethereum wallet that auto adds the tokens without manual input of the token contract?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Though I use the iOS versions, so can't vouch for the Android versions.

Do your own research, each has their strengths. You are generally providing your private key which controls things you value. I recommend don’t have keys in mobile wallets controlling more than $50 worth of stuff. For valuables use a hardware wallet to store your keys.

The following is a short list of mobile wallets that have automagical display of ERC20 and ERC721 (I love collectibles) tokens for addresses (these are not the only ones, just some of the ones I have used and are still on my phone):

- Trust Wallet https://trustwallet.com
- Coinbase Wallet https://wallet.coinbase.com
- Opera Touch https://www.opera.com/mobile

Disclosure: I am friends with some wallet developers, so as always, do your own research on which ones to trust.

Comment: which wallet are you friends with?

Comment: Trust wallet doesn't work with most Bitcoin addresses, the devs refuse to support backwards compatibility

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ I am friends with a developer working on Trust Wallet.  I have also had interactions with several team members at Coinbase Wallet.  
As always, do your own research on a wallet to trust.

Answer (score 0):

## View it

You can get a list of token holdings by visiting [Amberdata.io](https://amberdata.io) and entering your address. There you'll be able to [see your token holdings](https://amberdata.io/addresses/0x3f5ce5fbfe3e9af3971dd833d26ba9b5c936f0be/portfolio). Like for instance:

[image]

## Build it

If you're interested in developing a wallet that does this automatically you could use Amberdata's API to [get the token holdings of any address](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference#get-address-tokens):

There's also an [example wallet app](https://amberdata.github.io/amberdata-example-erc20-wallet/) you can check out:

[image]

It can even include pricing data like so:

[image]

Hope that helps at all!